# Effective conversion of strings with date "31. 12. 2019" and "7/2020" to the date type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am importing CSV files that contain dates in two alternative forms like:

- `31. 12. 2019`
- `7/2020`

The two forms may alternatively occur in the same column; so, the part of the solution have to be detection of the form.

As the second form `7/2020` does not contain the day information, I am using 1 for the day.

So far, I have worked only with the subset of records that used predictable form of the used date. I have followed the T-SQL documentation for the `CONVERT()` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). Let's assume `@date = '31. 12. 2019'` then the following conversion is done:

```sql
    CONVERT(date, @date, 104) AS my_date         -- the German form
```

For the `@date = '7/2020'` I do the following:

```sql
    CONVERT(date, '1/' + @date, 103) AS my_date  -- the British/French form
```

Now, if I do not know (in advance) what form the `@date` contains, how to convert it?

Actually, the date is not in a `@date` variable. Instead, it is the field value in the `SELECT` query -- say `xdate`. I expect the code to look like:

```sql
    CASE WHEN /* detect the British/French case */ THEN CONVERT(date, '1/' + xdate, 103)
         WHEN /* detect the German case */ THEN CONVERT(date, xdate, 104)
         ELSE NULL -- this does not happen, anyway...
    END AS my_date
```

... but there may be some better way.

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using? What is the compatibility level?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts: SQL 2014 and was 100. Changed to 120.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, a possible solution is a combination of `COALESCE()` and `TRY_CONVERT()`:

Statement:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
   TRY_CONVERT(date, xdate, 104), 
   TRY_CONVERT(date, '1/' + xdate, 103)
) AS xdate
FROM (VALUES
   ('31. 12. 2019'),
   ('7/2000'),
   ('wrong date 12/12')
) v (xdate)
```

Result:

```
xdate
----------
2019-12-31
2000-07-01
null
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to learn how to increase the compatibility level to use TRY_CONVERT. Anyway, this solution seems to be about twice faster than the CASE WHEN solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple `charindex` can get you an indication of the string contains a slash (`/`) or not - which is a good enough indication if the text format is `m/yyyy` or `dd. mm. yyyy`.

However, you should use `Try_convert` and not `convert` because a case expression isn't guaranteed to short-circuit, meaning all `when` clauses might be evaluated.

Here's how I would write it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', xdate) > 0 THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, '1/' + xdate, 103)
            ELSE TRY_CONVERT(date, xdate, 104)
       END As my_date
```

Comment: I like that. However the COALESCE solution seems to be about two times faster.

Comment: Actually, I'm kinda sorry I didn't think about the coalesce option to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're dumping the CSV into a table using bulk insert or some similar process, and the column in that table storing the unprocessed date is a `varchar`, and then you're running a query against the table to process the contents, yeah?

If that's the case, and there are only ever those two forms, you could use `like`, or `charindex()`. The performance is going to be pretty much the same as far as I know, so do whichever seems easier to read. Personally I'd probably use `charindex`:

```
select case 
          when charindex('/', xdate) > 0 then convert(date, '1/' + xdate, 103)
          else convert(date, xdate, 104)
       end
```

Or using `like`:

```
select case 
          when xdate like '%/%' then convert(date, '1/' + xdate, 103)
          else convert(date, xdate, 104)
       end
```

If those aren't the only two forms then you probably want to `try_convert` instead, or just cover all of your bases